# Setting DateTimePicker to Null and saving to DB

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I am having issues with my `DateTimePicker`. I have followed all examples for setting my `DateTimePicker` to be blank. The code looks like this:

```
dtpCloseDate.Checked = false;
dtpCloseDate.ShowCheckBox = false;

if (dtpCloseDate.Checked == false)
{
    dtpCloseDate.CustomFormat = " ";
    dtpCloseDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
}
```

So this works great when loaded the `DateTimePicker` loads up with a blank in there. However, behind the scenes there is actually a date being loaded into this. So I then save to the DB and it has a date. Plus I am trying to validate that this close date is after the open date. I do have the validation, but it is always triggered currently because there is a date in the close date that is apparently before the open date.

Comment: What date is it saving?

Comment: Current DateTime is being saved into the DB.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work either.  I'd start thinking of a work around -- like having a fixed date 0 and testing for that instead of null.   You might try to have your database allow nulls and then don't insert that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe do this:

```
dtpCloseDate.Checked = false;
dtpCloseDate.ShowCheckBox = false;

if (dtpCloseDate.Checked == false)
{
    dtpCloseDate.CustomFormat = " ";
    dtpCloseDate.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    dtpCloseDate.Value = DateTime.MinValue;
}
```

to set the date to absolute zero. Then test that when loading/saving to the database/doing whatever you wanna do:

```
if (dtp.Value == DateTime.MinValue) { ... }
```

Comment: Yes a work around is what was needed. So I set it to `DateTime.FromOADate(0)` because `DateTime.MinValue` didn't want to work. Then I just used: `if (dtp.Value == DateTime.FromOADate(0)) { ... }` around where I was loading/saving or validating.

Comment: Awesome, the MinValue thing might be my fault. I didn't run the code... 